# Switching between display:none and display:block with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

So, my goal is to make my first div

```
<a href="#" onclick="showVideo1()">
<div style="width:42.5%; height:50%; position:absolute; top:5%; left:5%;     background:black;" onclick="toggle_visibility('video1');">
<video style="width:100%; height:100%" autoplay="autoplay" loop="true" muted>
<source src="http://www.techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
</a>
```

change the display of div2

```
<div class="hiddiv" id="video1">
<div class="vidcont">
<video style="width:100%; height:100%;">
<source src="http://www.techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
</div>
```

when its clicked. To do so, I used this bit of JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function showVideo1() {
 document.getElementById('video1').style.display = "block";
 }
</script>`
```

and it works how I want it to, but now I need it so when I click on div2, it changes back to hidden. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can just create another function to hide it

```
<div class= "hiddiv" id="video1" onclick="hideVideo()">
...
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function hideVideo() {
 document.getElementById('video1').style.display = "none";
 }
</script>
```

you can also create a function to toggle classes (visible/hidden).